# Is there any automated converter of MooTools Plugins to jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, mootools, porting

I found this [memo on porting some moo tools plugin to jquery](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2010/07/08/porting-mootools-to-jquery/). But if it is all needed and it is so short has any one automated it? Or there are other porting rules and general incompatibilities between jQuery and MooTools that can't be automatically solved by simple stuff like `find all this, replace with self; find all .href, replace with .attr('href'); ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: MooTools and jQuery have completely different approaches to getting things done, MooTools is a modular framework, where's jQuery is just a toolkit. One cannot just replace method names, and expect things to work. You'd need to understand the differences, then port the code, keeping in mind the methodology of the specific framework/toolkit.

For more reading, and understanding visit: http://jqueryvsmootools.com/